# How do inanimate objects eat devil fruit?

Tags: one-piece

Devil fruit users gained their powers by eating the devil fruit. But how did these inanimate objects gain their power?

This is Luffy, eating a devil fruit before he became a rubber man.

[image]

And this is Lassoo, one of Mr.4's guns that became a dog. How did a gun ate it?

[image]

Comment: I have read that Dr. Vegapunk's research has led him to devise the method that lets an inanimate object (such as a gun or a sword) gain the effect of a Devil Fruit (although it has not yet been shown how this is done)

Comment: This means that maybe black beard is able to use two devil fruits because one of them was consumed by an object he uses, maybe a ring, his sword or his gun

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, Dr. Vegapunk's scientific expertise is the logic behind an inanimate object being able to "consume" a devil fruit.

> Dr. Vegapunk covered exactly how Devil Fruit powers are transferred over to a user, and was the scientist behind the method of adding Devil Fruit powers to inanimate objects, such as swords and guns.<sup>[Source](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Vegapunk)</sup>

This is the only known research paper of his related to this experiment:

[image]

The inanimate objects who have eaten Devil Fruits are:

- [Mr. 4](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._4)'s  gun, [Lassoo](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Lassoo)
- [Spandam](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Spandam)'s sword, [Funkfreed](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Funkfreed).

It is also notable that the only Devil Fruits shown to be capable of achieving such a feat are Zoan devil fruits. It may be because Logia and Paramecia only grant the users supernatural powers, which would not bring the objects to life.

This is all that is known about the matter.

> According to Oda, a "certain professor" will explain the complex mechanisms behind all of the Devil Fruits in the series in the near future. <sup>[Source](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit#cite_note-0)</sup>

Comment: Perhaps this is the most accepted explanation as for the moment because nothing is completely revealed yet.

Comment: Also, Smiley was an inanimate object, which ate a devil fruit